# Calculating time taken to submit a form excluding the network delay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I want to make a quiz like application in which the user will be given a specific time ( Eg. 1 minute ) to answer a question. Currently I am using a timer to submit the form automatically on timeout. But i need to make sure that no one is able to bypass the timer. So I decided to create a checking on the server side to check if the first request and the form submission was between a fixed amount of time. But how could I handle the network delay in PHP. If my network takes 10 seconds to load the form and 5 seconds to submit the form, my total time would be 1 minute 15 seconds. Any better solutions ?

Client

```
<body onload="myFunc">
  <form action="submit.php" id="myForm" method="POST">
    <h4>My Question</h4>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your answer">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

<script>
function myFunc(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit();
  },60*1000);
}
</script>
```

Server

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){
     echo "The form...";
     $_SESSION['start'] = time();
  }else{
     $end = time();
     if($end - $_SESSION['start'] > 60){ // Need help here. It will be always > 60
        echo "You are too late..";
     }
     else{
        echo "Submitted";
     }
  }
?>
```

There may be syntax errors in the code. It's not the correct code, I was trying to explain my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that handles with javascript you can't rely on it because the user can change it in client side.probably the best solution is that you have startTime on your server side in your database and when you in your server side you got request save finish time and see that it's normal or not.

For getting network delay you can set send time in client side with javascript but the user can manipulate it and it's not reliable.
you can get UTC timestamp from javascript like this:

```
var now = new Date;
var utc_timestamp = Date.UTC(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(), now.getDate() , 
      now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(), now.getMilliseconds());
```

or you can set a timer from start of the exam and when form submitted or exam finished count number of second that has passed and send it to server but as already I said it can be change by user

Maybe with obfusticating your javascript code you be more trust to your javascript and data that you recievd from client side

Comment: If I send time from client side, how can I make sure that the time on server and client are same.